# Spotify API Temporary Playlist not working correctly

Tags: javascript, spotify, playlist

I am trying to create a temporary playlist from a set of songs and display the playlist. For some reason, the playlist will randomly leave out a song or two on the screen and sometimes it works perfectly. No idea why.

```
var SortSongsMakeList = function(data)
{
    SortSongs(data);

    document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = "";

    models.Playlist.createTemporary('Server Songs').done(function(playlist) 
    {
        playlist.load('tracks').done(function(loadedPlaylist)
        {
           for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
           {
               loadedPlaylist.tracks.add(models.Track.fromURI(data[i].song_uri));
           }
     });

     var newList = List.forPlaylist(playlist);
     document.querySelector('h1').appendChild(newList.node);
     newList.init();

     playlist.tracks.clear();

     // Remove the temporary ones not in use to reduce resource load
     models.Playlist.removeTemporary( models.Playlist.fromURI(playlist.uri) );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're better off setting all the tracks at once with an array, like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21053309/9970